# Get ISO code of Primary Currency of Customer in NetSuite via Saved search

Tags: netsuite

I am new to NetSuite formula expressions used in saved searches and i am trying to return the ISO Code of the Primary Currency of Customer Record.

Tried {currency.symbol}. But it is throwing invalid Field error

Answer (score 2):

You're sort of hosed. Currency isn't properly joined to customer so all you can get is the name of the currency.

As far as I know there are no clean ways to get the symbol into a saved search result. The best way would be a non-stored formula field that uses a case statement to go from currency to currency symbol.

If this is your only need for this value you can put such a formula into your search:

```
decode({currency},'USA','USD', 'Euro','EUR','RMB', 'CNY', {currency})
```

this makes use of the fact that for a number of currencies in NS the name is the symbol (e.g. AUD, CAD).

To get a list of the currencies and their mappings in your account run something like the following in a console window:

```
var currSymbs = nlapiSearchRecord('currency', null, null,
                           [new nlobjSearchColumn('name'),
                            new nlobjSearchColumn('symbol')
                            ]);
currSymbs.forEach(function(c){
   console.log(c.getId() +': '+c.getValue('name') +' is '+  c.getValue('symbol'));
});

// or even create the decode statement with the script and keep it as a bookmarklet:

console.log("decode({currency},"+currSymbs.map(function(c){
    return "'"+c.getValue('name') +"','"+ c.getValue('symbol')+"'";}).
  join(',') +","+"'not mapped')");
```

Answer (score 0):

See first if you can get the field a without the formula. Some fields are not available on reports but are on the internal api.

Comment: I can get that currency field without the formula, But it is returning Currency Name.I want currency ISO code